# Rows are NOT displaying in Lightning data table in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The records are not displayed in the lighting data table and look like the below. I could see the data coming through when I checked in the console but not displaying the table. Could someone please help me with this as I am unable to identify where the issue is? Many thanks!!

[image: lighting Data Table]

**Apex Controller Class**

```apex
public with sharing class MissingWebUserListCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<WebUsers> getWebUsers(){
        try{
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            //Getting Endpoint details from Named Credentials    
            request.setEndpoint('callout:MissingUsers');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
                    
            system.debug('data' + (List<WebUsers>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<WebUsers>.class));
            return  (List<WebUsers>) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<WebUsers>.class);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled    
    public static void createWebUsers(List<sObject> webUserObject){
        List<Web_User__c> webUser = (List<Web_User__c>) webUserObject;
        insert webUser;
    }
    
    public class WebUsers {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Id { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Name { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Username { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Email { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public Company company  { get; set; }    
    }

    public class Company {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name {get; set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public String catchPhrase  {get; set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public String bs {get; set;} 
    }
}
```

**WebUser.cmp**

```html
<aura:component description="MissingWebUserList" implements="force:appHostable" controller="MissingWebUserListCtrl" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this }" action="{!c.init }"/>
    
    <lightning:card title="Missing User to Import">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="Import Missing Record" onclick="{!c.doSave}"/> 
        </aura:set>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning:datatable
                                 keyField="Id"
                                 data="{!v.data}"
                                 columns="{!v.columns}"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
        </p>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**WebUserController.js**

```javascript
({
    init : function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.columns", [
            {label: 'Id', fieldName: 'id', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'User Name', fieldName: 'username', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email'},
            {label: 'Company Name', fieldName: 'company.name', type: 'text'}
        ]);
        
        var action = component.get("c.getWebUsers");         
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('State :', state)
            console.log('response.getReturnValue :', response.getReturnValue())
            if(state ==  'SUCCESS'){
                component.set("v.data", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if(state ==="ERROR"){
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

  doSave: function(component, event, helper) {
    let action = component.get("c.createWebUsers");
    action.setParams({ webUserObject: component.get("v.data") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
      component.set("v.data", data.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
});
```

Comment: make sure your column field names match (case-sensitive) your response's object. eg.:  `fieldName: 'id'` should be `fieldName: 'Id'` (based on the image you provided)

Comment: Dear @McCubo - Thank you so much it works when I changed it to `fieldName: 'Id'`. However, the Company Name is not populating. Below is the return object structure.

`WebUsers:[Email=Sincere@april.biz, Id=1, Name=Leanne Graham, Username=Bret, company=Company:[bs=harness real-time e-markets, catchPhrase=Multi-layered client-server neural-net, name=Romaguera-Crona]`

Would you please suggest if you have any idea?

Comment: I think nested properties are not supported by the datatable component, so one possible solution could be create a new string property containing the company name value, so you'd need to: change this: `fieldName: 'company.name'` to `fieldName: 'companyName'` (in your column definition). then, in your callback function: add this line before assigning the `v.data` variable: `let newResponse = response.getReturnValue().map(webUser => { return Object.assign({companyName: webUser.company.name}, webUser) });`, and finally: `component.set("v.data", newResponse);`

Comment: Many thanks, @McCubo! It works after I made changes as you suggested.

Comment: @McCubo - I need to save the lightning data-table records that come from external system into a custom object. I have a `doSave` function that would be called by `onclcik` event when the user clicks lightning-button on the component. There is an apex controller method `createWebUsers` to save the data-table records to the object (Eg: Fields: Username__c, Email__c, Company__c). However, the records are not saving. Would you mind sharing any thoughts on this? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi @Giri K, I'm happy to help, but I think it would be best if you create a new question post, otherwise a moderator could delete this post and we would lost access to it.

Comment: @McCubo - Thanks for your suggestion. I just posted a new question.

Comment: @McCubo - Here is the new post:
[link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382267/how-to-save-lightning-data-table-data-in-aura-component-to-a-custom-object-when)