# How to INSERT Lightning datatable records in Aura component to a custom object when a button is clicked

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have a requirement to save lightning data-table records,  fetches from the external system, into a custom object. The controller.js `doSave` function would be called by the `onclcik` event when the custom lightning-button `Save Records` clicked. The apex controller method `createWebUsers` created to save data-table records into the custom object (Eg: Fields: Username__c, Email__c, Company__c).

There is no exception when the button is clicked, but no records are inserted into the custom object. I can see that object `webUserRecords` that is passed to the apex method contains the data. I couldn't identify what I am missing. Would you please help me with this? Thank you!

**Console log of V.data passed to createWebUsers controller method**
[image]

**System.debug() log of createWebUsers apex method**
[image]

**Apex Controller Class**

```apex
public with sharing class MissingWebUserListCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<WebUsers> getWebUsers(){
        try{
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            //Getting Endpoint details from Named Credentials    
            request.setEndpoint('callout:MissingUsers');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
                    
            return  (List<WebUsers>) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<WebUsers>.class);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled    
    public static void createWebUsers(List<sObject> webUserObject){
        List<Web_User__c> webUser = (List<Web_User__c>) webUserObject;
        insert webUser;
    }
    
    public class WebUsers {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Id { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Name { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Username { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Email { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public Company company  { get; set; }    
    }

    public class Company {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name {get; set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public String catchPhrase  {get; set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public String bs {get; set;} 
    }
}
```

**WebUser.cmp**

```html
<aura:component description="MissingWebUserList" implements="force:appHostable" controller="MissingWebUserListCtrl" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this }" action="{!c.init }"/>
    
    <lightning:card title="Missing User to Import">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="Save Records" onclick="{!c.doSave}"/> 
        </aura:set>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning:datatable
                                 keyField="Id"
                                 data="{!v.data}"
                                 columns="{!v.columns}"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
        </p>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**WebUserController.js**

```javascript
({
    init : function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.columns", [
            {label: 'Id', fieldName: 'id', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'User Name', fieldName: 'username', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email'},
            {label: 'Company Name', fieldName: 'company.name', type: 'text'}
        ]);
        
        var action = component.get("c.getWebUsers");         
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('State :', state)
            console.log('response.getReturnValue :', response.getReturnValue())
            if(state ==  'SUCCESS'){
               let newResponse = response.getReturnValue().map(webUser => {
               return Object.assign({ companyName: webUser.company.name }, webUser);
            });
               component.set("v.data", newResponse);
            }
            else if(state ==="ERROR"){
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

  /* doSave: function(component, event, helper) {
    let action = component.get("c.createWebUsers");
    action.setParams({'webUserObject': component.get("v.data") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
      component.set("v.data", data.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }*/

  doSave: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.saveDataTable(component, event, helper);
  }

});
```

**Helper.js**

```javascript
({
  saveDataTable: function(component, event, helper) {
    let  webUserRecords = component.get("v.data");
    console.log('webUserRecords', webUserRecords);
    let totalRecordInsertted = webUserRecords.length;
    let action = component.get("c.createWebUsers");
    action.setParams({
      webUserObject: webUserRecords
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        //if update is successful
        if (response.getReturnValue() === true) {
          helper.showToast({
            title: "",
            type: "success",
            message: totalRecordInsertted + " Missing Web Users Inserted"
          });
          helper.reloadDataTable();
        } else {
          //if update got failed
          helper.showToast({
            title: "Error!!",
            type: "error",
            message: "Error in update"
          });
        }
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },

  showToast: function(params) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    if (toastEvent) {
      toastEvent.setParams(params);
      toastEvent.fire();
    } else {
      alert(params.message);
    }
  },

  reloadDataTable: function() {
    var refreshEvent = $A.get("e.force:refreshView");
    if (refreshEvent) {
      refreshEvent.fire();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: _However, the records are not saving_ is not a useful statement. Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, *Complete* and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Giri K, if you open the developer console, are you getting any exception (if so, add them to your question)? could you add a `console.log` for your data variable on your callback? also if you could add a `System.debug` for webUserObject list on your apex method. and paste the results on your question, that way would be easier to provide you with guidance.

Comment: @McCubo, thank you very much for getting back to me. I have update controller.js helper .js code and attached console and debug logs. Please help me with this issue. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @GiriK I think the casting you are doing is not working since the properties you are sending from JS are not the same as the properties in your SObject,, eg: you are sending `Email` from JS, but your SObject property is `Email__c`, hence I think you need to manually iterate your `webUserObject` and create a new list of `Web_User__c`. I hope what I said makes sense to you.